# Почему PrintDocument может печатать пустые листы?

Tags: c#

Использую код из [примера](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=netframework-4.8), столкнулся с одной интересной ситуацией
Программа работает на моем домашнем компьютере с моим принтером №1
Работает на 3 разных компьютеров с принтером №2 в офисе

Работает у заказчика с его принтером №3 с двух других компьютеров
Но на третьем компьютере заказчика не работает с тем же самым принтером
Но тот компьютер печатает с других программ

И так, у меня есть софт который не печатает только на одном ПК (выходят белые листы)
На этом ПК другой софт печатает без проблем
Мой софт работает с тем же самым принтером нормально на других ПК

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Может быть там с окружением что-то не так, версия винды, что угодно. Пробовали докер?

Comment: Смотрите настройки драйвера принтера на этом ПК.